# Filter dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

```
columnA    columnB    columnC    columnD
A           BB           10         20
A           AA           15         15
B           AA           20         10
```

And another dataframe df2:

```
columnA   columnB
A           BB
B           AA
```

How can I filter the dataframe `df` in a pythonic way that I only keep the values if the subdataframe `df2` have the excat combination of `columnA` and `columnB`.
The expected output for df is:

```
columnA    columnB    columnC    columnD
A           BB           10         20
B           AA           20         10
```

Comment: `df1.merge(df2)` or `df1.merge(df2[['columnA', 'columnB']])` if `df2` has more columns.